# RegEx for CSS body {height:100%}

Tags: javascript, css, regex

Using Javascript, I'm parsing a DOM Style Sheet object (document.styleSheets[0] for instance) - looking for any CSS rules that set the height of the body to any percentage value.

I've come up with this RegEx that does the job - but I'm wondering if there's any way to optimize it ?

```
,?\s*(body)\s*({|,).*(height)\s*:\s*(\d+%)\s*(!important)?;
```

This RegEx finds any CSS rule where the selector applies to the body, and the rule content (i.e. actual CSS properties) include a 'height' property with a percentage value.
For example:

```
body { height:100%}
```

Or:

```
html, body { width: 100%; height: 100%; }
```

Or:

```
body, h1 { height:100% !important; }
```

etc..

So I was wondering if there's a better way to write this RegEx ?

Comment: You know you can get the rules and content with `styleSheets[0].rules` etc. as styleDeclarations instead of parsing everything with regex ?

Comment: Thanks! Do you mean through `styleSheets[0].cssRules` ?
If so - then yes, I'm actually looping through all of those (is there a better way ?)

Comment: @UJC If you don't mind taking a small performance hit, you can test for `<body>` or `<html>` in the _NodeList_ returned by `document.querySelectorAll(rule.selectorText)`, and if you find one, check for a `rule.style.height` - this will give you the exact results you want. There is also the vendor prefixed `node.matchesSelector`; i.e. `node.webkitMatchesSelector('body'); // gives true or false depending on node`

Comment: @PaulS. Thx. Don't mind the performance hit in this case. I thought of walking through a node list, but found that some browsers will return the CSS value in pixels. In my specific scenario I need to know if the CSS-unit used for `height` are percentage or not. Thoughts ?

Comment: @UJC So `window.getComputedStyle(node)` is a no-go? I would've gone with that. If you're looking at every rule and finding all those which match, you may have some problems "choosing" which selector that matches to actually go with, i.e. `html > body` matches over `body` matches over `*`, but there could be an `!important`, later ones with the same selector override earlier ones, etc etc.

Comment: @PaulS. Yup, `getComputedStyle` is a no-go );
I see what you mean..that helps - thanks for pointing this out!
Given the limitations of my scenario, anything else I should try ? (other than a more-complex RegEx ?)

Edit: I only need to find one match, then I stop the loop and act upon that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would try this regex:

```
/body[^{]*?\{[\s\S]*?(height\s*:\s*\d+%)[\s\S]*?\}/i
```

#### Description

[image: Regular expression visualization]

#### Demo

http://regex101.com/r/lX5cC9